# How to get the total size of data matching query ElasticSearch?

Tags: elasticsearch

I have an ES query, that looks like this (I'm running it via [Sense](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/sense-beta/lhjgkmllcaadmopgmanpapmpjgmfcfig?hl=en)):

```
GET /asdf/qwer/_search
{
  "query": {
    "filtered": {
      "filter": {
        "bool": {
          "must": [
            { "term": { "some_name": "some_value" } }
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

This query has a huge number of results. What I really need to know is how much space these results are taking up in my cluster. Is there any way to get that kind of stat out of ES?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think this is possible in ES.

Maybe you can extrapolate by taking a look at the statistics related to your index, on how many docs these statistics are considered, then approximate the same for a subset of those documents (given the number of documents your query returns).

```
GET /_stats/store,docs?index=test
```

Answer (score 0):

This is possible using the [_size field](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/plugins/current/mapper-size-usage.html).

```
GET /asdf/qwer/_search
{
    "size": 0,
    "query": {
        "match_all": {}
    },
    "fields": [
        "_size"
    ],
    "aggs": {
        "total_size": {
            "sum": {
                "field": "_size"
            }
        }
    }
}
```